What physical processes are involved in causing the Voigt profile in X-ray diffraction
I understand qualitatively that a Voigt profile combines both Gaussian and Lorentzian profiles which is a suitable method for plotting an X-ray diffraction pattern.
Which physical processes lead to both of these profiles?
I understand the error is a combination of lifetime broadening, randomness of the source, and intrinsic uncertainty in the wavelength of the X-rays etc, but which contribute to the different profiles and why?
